# What will happen if i put colored toner in Black white laser printer cartridge

Tags: printer, toner

Just out of Curoisity what will happen if i put green color toner in black and white cartridge.

Will it print green.

I remember in B/W inkjet printer i put the blue ink and it started prinitng blue

Is same case with laser toners

Comment: Why not try it like you did with the inkjet?

Comment: That was about 8 years ago and the cartridge was around 30$. so i could take the risk but idon't want to risk this 130$ cartridge for that but yes after 3-4 refills i will give it a go. You won't beleive it i put the PEN ink bottle (2$) in my HP cartridge and it worked . I printed around 15000 pages using those inks

Comment: It would be *really* great if it didn't print green, but some other color.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it will print green. The machine doesn't really "sense" what exact color of ink is inside the cartridge, but some can read the sensor and see if it is the right catridge, however that means nothing if you put a different color in it yourself. It counts on the user to fill them and insert them correctly. It can sense the amount of ink left, however :)

Answer (score 2):

Aren't the cartridges key-coded, to prevent inserting the wrong color in the wrong slot?

For some printers, it's done electronically: the ink cartridge has a small electronic part that tells the printer which color it is, how full it is, whether it's a genuine cartridge or a third-party one ...

Comment: Not because they wouldn't work, but to prevent inattentive users putting cartridges in the wrong place and getting confusing results.

Answer (score 2):

The printer will use the toner you put into the cartridge, but the quality of output and what it does to your OPC drum and fuser will depend on whether the toner has the same characteristics as the regular black stuff for that printer. There is a risk of clogging up these parts and reducing their life if the toner is not fully compatible.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't be green!

It will be a muddy gross black and green smudgy mess...

At least for the first few (no idea how many) pages

Answer (score 2):

The printer's electronics don't care about the color of the toner.  The printer will simply produce printouts with the color of the toner.  However, different types of toner may not behave as the printer expects, and this is very likely to cause the printer to malfunction.  In particular, the OPC drum, transfer belt, rollers, and fuser may not like getting a different type or color of toner than it expects while printing.

Furthermore, as Simon notes, because of contamination by residual toner in the cartridge, the first [xxx] pages may be colored as a mixture of the two toner colors.